# cd - 1>&2 >/dev/null doesn't work right on Solaris

Tags: solaris

I use a command in a script for AIX and RHEL:

```
cd - 1>&2 >/dev/null
```

I know that this is trying to go back to the previous directory after changing to another directory.

While the exact same logic works for AIX and RHEL, it’s apparently not quite working on Solaris, with the error that I got implying that there’s no previous directory to go back to, when in fact the script had change the directory to `/etc/opt/esmsym`.

How to make this work on Solaris?

Do you have an alternative?

Comment: `1>&2` should be `2>&1` if you're looking to redirect stderr to stdout. As for you actual question, are you sure `cd -` is supported on Solaris?

Comment: cd - is working but not cd - 1>&2 >/dev/null. Thanks

Comment: @adamdunson, `cd -` is more of a shell feature than an OS one. @user2639251, can you provide more evidence this is not working ? I do not reproduce the issue with either bash or ksh under Solaris 10. As already stated, your first redirection make no sense, being overloaded by the second one. Can you post the precise command you are running, the precise shell used and the error message you get ?

Answer (score 0):

try running:

```
cd $OLDPWD
```

That should take you back to the previous working directory.

Or, if that doesn't work then you could try using this:

```
export path=$(pwd)

cd ~/B/
cd $path
```

This saves a copy of the current path to the `$path` variable and then changes the current directory to `~/B/` and then uses the `$path` variable to return the to previous working directory.

---

Just as a side-note, there's also `podp` and `pushd`

```
pushd $(pwd)

cd /tmp

popd
```

Taken from [popd(1)](http://www.manpages.spotlynx.com/solaris/man/popd.1):

```
pushd pushes a directory onto the directory stack. With no arguments, exchange the top two elements.

   +n
       Rotate the n’th entry to the top of the stack and cd to it.
   dir
       Push the current working directory onto the stack and change to dir.

popd pops the directory stack and cd to the new top directory. The elements of 
the directory stack are numbered from 0 starting at the top.

   +n
       Discard the n’th entry in the stack.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I would go for the alternatives instead find out why cd - 1>&2 >/dev/null is not working on Solaris

Comment: @user2639251 You're welcome, just glad that I could help.  :)